# How is an event passed to a javascript method?

Tags: javascript, events

There are several answers for how to pass an "artificial" event in javascript.

What I dont understand is how is the event passed to the method AND event if not passed be accessible by directly using the "event" variable even though it doesnt seem to be declared anywhere.

Can someone explain this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rudimentary event listener:

```
class EventCaller {
    constructor() {
        this.listeners = [];
    }

    addListener(obj) {
        if (obj.trigger) { this.listeners.push(obj); }
    }

    trigger(event, ..data) {
        this.listeners.forEach((listener) => listener.trigger(event, ...data));
    }
}

class EventListener {
    constructor() { this.eventsListeningTo = []; }

    listenTo(item) {
        if (!item.addListener) { throw new Error('Cannot add listener error'); }
        item.addListener(this);
    }

    trigger(event, ...data) {
        if (this[`on${event}`]) {this[`on${event}`](...data)}
    }

    onFoo({bar, foo}) {
       console.log(bar, foo);
    }
}
```

Then as an example you can create an `EventCaller`:

```
const eventAgg = new EventCaller();
```

Then create a few event listeners

```
const a = new EventListener();
const b = new EventListener();
```

Then a and b can listen on `eventAgg` events

a.listenTo(eventAgg);
   b.listenTo(eventAgg);

So if now I trigger

```
eventAgg.trigger('Foo', {bar: 'lemons', foo: 42});
```

Now both `a` and `b` will console log out `lemons, 42` since they are both listening on that pseudo event.

---

This is just basics. jquery, Backbone, angular etc all implement this in different ways (I am sure) but it all comes down to callbacks (or even Promises in newer code)